# qInstallMessageHandler() analog in Qt 4.8?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to print from a method which prints something in stdout to QTextWidget.

My function looks like this:

```
void Worker::runSomething()
{
someOtherObject->aMethodWhichPrintsSomethingInSTDOUT();
}
```

qInstallMsgHandler looks good for this, but I'm using a qt4 with gcc4.4 on linux. So, maybe someone knows any analog for that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question.

[qInstallMessageHandler](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html) in Qt5 is the replacement function for the older [qInstallMsgHandler](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html) from Qt4